How to fix 0x80073701 error while installing IIS service on Azure Windows Server 2019?
I am facing error while installing IIS service on my Azure Windows Server 2019 from both the options i.e., through Server manager and via PowerShell command.
I checked various article to fix it but couldn't fix the issue including the one mentioned in below link.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowserver/forum/all/0x80073701-error-while-installing-iis-features-on/21c662d2-ed71-4e17-94c8-a571ebd5c235
In my previous organization, i remember facing similar issue for Azure Win 2019 VMs but at that time I used to explicitly provide some file path which the IIS command used to refer during installation through PowerShell. However i am not able to recollect the file name and its type and also didn't find any similar solution like it while browsing.
Could anyone please help me fixing this error and installing IIS?

Update --
While trying the suggested ISO install, the installation is not allowing to select Keep personal files and apps.


Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. The referenced assembly could not be found. Error: 0x80073701
What causes this issue to happen is that the Server OS installation is corrupt or installed with the wrong language pack. To resolve this installation issue, reinstall the Server OS using the correct language pack that matches the environment refer to the following steps.

Mount the Windows 2019 ISO with the correct Language pack(Mine is English.pack).


Run the setup.exe as an administrator.


Select Not right now
and then select
“keep all the data and files”.


Finish the installation.



Thanks alwa shuang, but installing this would delete all of my data from the VM or it will only install the language package and not the entire OS and would not affect my existing data on the VM?

@SRP During the installation process, you can choose to keep all data and only do the upgrade installation.

I tried installing it but its not allowing me to select the "Keep all personal files and apps" option instead its by default set to "Nothing" option. Screenshot above for reference.

Because you are trying to upgrade using an ISO file that is not applicable to the current installed release.
